# How to fetch data by weeks and have it display by switching between weeks?

Tags: javascript

I want to code something like this [where you can see the weeks and switch between them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mszMn.png). At the moment I wrote these days in HTML, so it is not dynamic. I am new to this, so I don't know what JS library can do something like this. I managed to find something that gives you the current week. However, I don't think this is the right approach.

```js
var  week = {
  period: null,

  load: function () {
    var d = new Date(); // today, now
     week.period = d.setDate(d.getDate() + ((7 - d.getDay()) % 7 + 1) % 7);
    document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = dayjs( week.period).format("DD/MMM/YYYY");
  },
  };

 week.load();
```

```html
 <h1 id="date"></h1>
```

This way I get the next Monday. How would you go from here? I want to first get the weeks done. I have the fetch under control, as I have JSON data.

Comment: You can use vanilla JS [date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) or [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) then display it in HTML with [select tag](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp) created dynamically like [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

Comment: @MariusROBERT FYI even moment.js authors recommend that you don't use moment.js anymore: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/